# Add new property to user profile using UserProfileService

Tags: sharepoint, web-services, user-profile

In MOSS 2007 using UserProfileService webservice I'm able to read/update an already existing property from a user profile. Is possible to use this webservice to create new properties ? If yes how ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not support adding new profile properties.  You will need to use the Office Server API.

Here is some more detail information. http://blogs.interakting.co.uk/danmatthews/archive/2007/04/24/40.aspx

Comment: If so, I will create a feature and add the code for the creation of property into feature activation (this code will run under admin account - this will use Office Server API). For the part of reading/updating properties I will continue to use the web service. In this way I will not need to provide "manage properties" rights to all authenticated users.